# How to use bitset(c++) in cython

Tags: c++, cython, bitset

I am writing a python code that needs an efficient data structure to hold MANY bits.

I think the container, `bitset` in C++, perfectly fits my need. Note I know there is a class `bitarray` in python that can provide the same functions.

However, I really need my code to be VERY fast, so I am going to use **cython** to make use of the efficiency of C++.

And since that, how can use `bitset` ???

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Not easily. The issue is that `bitset` is templated with a number indicating its length and Cython does not handle non-class templates (i.e. numbers) well.

Comment: @DavidW yes, It's the very evil.